# Nuclear physics on gravitational background

Tags: gravity, nuclear-physics, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Is there any treatment on nuclear physics in strong gravitational fields? (I tried to search over the Internet, but found references only on QFT on gravitational background)

Comment: I do not know enough to give a detailed answer. You should look into neutron stars as they are in the regime where nuclear physics and gravity interplay. This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but it might help you find some references.

Comment: Yes, neutron stars probably are the closest fenomenon to what I asked about, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, no, because they are descriptions that are relevant at very different scales (but there might be...). There are very few and remote settings where both gravity and particle physics play role. So let alone the nuclear regime, which pertains to energies that are somewhat lower than in particle physics.

As an example imagine you are trying to describe the motion of planets around the sun while simultaneously accounting for the mass shift because of ants moving on the earth.

So the question I can return to you is actually what kind of scenario are you imagining where gravity and nuclear forces are simultaneously relevant?

Comment: I'm wondering whether in some processes in cosmology there can simultaneously exist nuclei and gravitational fields strong enough to affect their properties, hence my question.